# SQL - Revert appended rows queried from Database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to reverse or somehow pivot appended rows from a table through an SQL Query. The following example illustrates the table structure I have

| Timestamp | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-18 | A | 10 |
| 2023-01-19 | A | 15 |
| 2023-01-20 | A | 20 |
| 2023-01-18 | B | 10 |
| 2023-01-19 | B | 15 |
| 2023-01-20 | B | 20 |
| 2023-01-18 | C | 10 |
| 2023-01-19 | C | 15 |
| 2023-01-20 | C | 20 |

And I am trying to modify the query to pivot or group the rows equivalent to the following:

| Timestamp | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-18 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-01-19 | 15 | 15 | 15 |
| 2023-01-20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

### What would be a solution for this query?

I have tried pivoting the query like the following which according to my research should do what I am hoping for, but maybe I am missing something as it returns an error message below.

```
SELECT Facility, 
       Site, 
       SUBSTRING(Name,
                 CHARINDEX('_',Name)+1,
                 ( ((LEN(Name)) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(Name))) 
                   - CHARINDEX('_',Name) )
       ) AS Panel, 
       dateadd(hh,-7,TimestampUTC) as TimeStamp, 
       ActualValue 
FROM PSS_KPIHistory 
WHERE Name LIKE '%PercentLoopsInNormal' 
PIVOT(ActualValue for Panel in(select distinct Panel from PSS_KPIHistory))
```

The above query returns columns Facility, Site, an extracted string from the column "Name" stored as new Column "Panel", a Timestamp and the Value (ActualValue). I am returning everything from the table that contains "PercentLoopsInNormal" in the "Name" Column. This returns the following error:

> Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'.
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Try going with the traditional approach. It can result clearer in code and won't impact efficiency of your query.

Comment: Sorry @lemon, could you elaborate on what the traditional approach is or how what references I can go through to understand this approach, please?

Comment: Everything before your pivot needs to go in a sub-query. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) shows how.

Comment: You also need an aggregate on ActualValue   for example sum(ActualValue )   HOWEVER,  your sample data and desired results and attempt  seem disconnected

Comment: You reference a field "*Name*" in your query, but in your sample data presented here there's no trace of it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @JohnCappelletti, I fixed it and it should make sense now.

Comment: @lemon, my apologies for the confusion, that query I posted is used on the "real" database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data doesn't fit your wanted result, changing it you can do

you would need a dynamic approach to the problem

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ([Timestamp] DATE, [ID] varchar(1), [Value] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    ([Timestamp], [ID], [Value])
VALUES
    ('2023-01-18', 'A', 10),
    ('2023-01-19', 'A', 15),
    ('2023-01-20', 'A', 20),
    ('2023-01-18', 'B', 10),
    ('2023-01-19', 'B', 15),
    ('2023-01-20', 'B', 20),
    ('2023-01-18', 'C', 10),
    ('2023-01-19', 'C', 15),
    ('2023-01-20', 'C', 20)
;
```

```
9 rows affected
```

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the Distinct ID
SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME( [ID]) + ','
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT [ID] FROM table1) t1
ORDER BY 
    [ID];

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
       [Timestamp], [ID], [Value]
    FROM 
        table1
) t 
PIVOT(
    MAX([Value])
    FOR [ID] IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;';
--SELECT @sql
-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

| Timestamp | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-18 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2023-01-19 | 15 | 15 | 15 |
| 2023-01-20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y9P16ird)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the traditional pivot approach:

- Step 1: identifying values from a single column that should be split in different columns (your discriminatory values are 'A', 'B' and 'C')
- Step 2: aggregating on the field for which specific value you want one record only in the output, in this case [Timestamp]

```
SELECT [Timestamp],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [ID] = 'A' THEN [Value] END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [ID] = 'B' THEN [Value] END) AS B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [ID] = 'C' THEN [Value] END) AS C
FROM tab
GROUP BY [Timestamp]
```

Typically Step1 requires the use of a window function, but in this case your [ID] field is ready to be used by Step2.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2vxk_AfM).